# python OSM map marker freezes the pyqt4 GUI

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am trying to make a GPS tracking GUI in pyQt4, i found this https://gist.github.com/ataffanel/13aac4b79bc0080b881f webkit that can display a map.
i want to take live GPS coordinates from my raspberry pi via TCP sockets and display a marker for each new sample, now to make things simple let's say i just want to add a function to`map.py` that takes latitude and longitude and displays a marker on the map.
i have been trying to do so with `frame.evaluateJavaScript("var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter().%s, map.getCenter().%s).addTo(map);" %(latt,lnn))`
when i inter my coordinates the map Freezes and no marker shows up.
 then i tried `frame.evaluateJavaScript("var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter()).addTo(map);")` the marker showed up but the map freezes,again. here is the function:

```
    def plotmap(self):
         lat=raw_input("enter latitude:")
         lon=raw_input("enter longtitude:")
         frame = self.view.page().mainFrame()
         frame.evaluateJavaScript("var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter().%s, map.getCenter().%s).addTo(map);" %(lat,lon))
```

at first i called it from outside the class. then as a button is clicked,both lead to freezing. then i tired defining the function outside the class and calling it separately but did not work either. how should i do it ?